# Using Apache Commons Math in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, apache, class

I am new to Java and Eclipse but familiar with other languages.

I want to use

```
public static Iterator<int[]> combinationsIterator(int n, int k)
```

I found it on http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-math/apidocs/org/apache/commons/math3/util/CombinatoricsUtils.html

I have Eclipse installed but I don't know where to go from here. What do I import? What do I have to reference in the header of my code before I can use `combinationsIterator`? Thank you.

Comment: Java libraries are (commonly) packaged as `.jar` files. You need to get the `.jar` file for the library you intend to use and add it to the **classpath** of your project at compilation _and_ execution time.

Comment: download the jar from below url
http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-math/download_math.cgi
add to your project and in java-build path add that jar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to go download the jar (for [their website](http://commons.apache.org) and add it to Eclipe's classpath.

You want the Math package, which can be downloaded [here](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-math/download_math.cgi).

To add it to the classpath, go to Eclipse, right click on your project, go to Properties -> Java Build Path -> Libraries -> Add External Jar and select the jar you downloaded.

Comment: I edited my main post with my progress, please advise.

Comment: @user3633260 That's a different question altogether. Ask a new question for that.